# Python Docker Image ImportError: python-magic

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-magic

Trying to create a very basic python image with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN pip3 install python-magic
```

The build works fine but when I try to run the container and simply `import magic`, python gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/magic.py", line 201, in <module>
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
```

I have googled and tried all different types of installtions such as:

```
RUN pip3 install python-magic
RUN pip3 install python-magic==0.4.18
RUN pip3 install python-libmagic
```

I don't know what is so special about this package but for some reason I can't seem to access it in my docker image. Works fine on my local mac computer.

Comment: Try that :
"RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmagic1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*"

Before pip3 install

Comment: tried it, gave a bunch of errors and `import magic` still didn't work.

Comment: Actually it did work, I had to use `pip3 install python-magic`

Comment: You were missing the debian package, then you can install the python module.